# Can't install Intel Fortran

Tags: 12.04, intel, fortran

I have installed package `Parallel Studio XE 2013 update1` on my Ubuntu 12.04 system in order to install CMAQ software and IOAPI3.1. But when I type `ifort` in my terminal it says:

```
ifort: Command not found.
```

What should I do to activate my Intel Fortran?

Comment: the package I named is a set of compilers like intel fortran and intel c. The package installation target was to have a intel fortran instead of gnu fortran.

Comment: You can always edit your question to supply additional information.

Comment: I couldn't find that package in the "standard" Ubuntu archives. Could you please specify the exact package name and where did you get it? Also, `dpkg -L <name-of-the-package>` will give you a list of files provided by the package. Check its output (looking especially for files in `bin` directories) and paste it in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Andrea but it was resolved by intel community. They told to source *.csh files in bin directory and it resolved the problem. (It was a package I downloaded from intel website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was resolved by the help of intel community. I sourced the *.csh (I am using tcsh) files in bin directory where I installed my compilers. They accepted "source" command with "intel64" as the parameter so it resolved it.